# Factorise $x^5-x$ in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]$

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I would like general feedback on my solution to this exercise.

### Exercise

Factorise $x^5-x$ in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

### Solution

In $\mathbb{C}[x]$ we have
\begin{align*}
&\phantom{=}\,\,\,x^5-x\\
&=x(x^4-1)\\
&=x(x^2-1)(x^2+1)\\
&=x(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)\\
&=x(x-1)(x+1)(x-i)(x+i)
\end{align*}

which is a factorisation into irreducibles because the factors are all linear.

In $\mathbb{R}[x]$ we have, as before, $x^5-x = x(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)$.

Assume $x^2+1$ has a root $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Then, $a\in\mathbb{C}$.

But $(x^2+1)=(x-i)(x+i)$ in $\mathbb{C}[x]$, which has roots $\pm i$. So by the uniqueness of polynomial factorisation, $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is impossible.

So a contradiction is reached, and $x^2+1$ does not have a root $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

So $x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Because the rest of the factors are linear terms, $x^5-x = x(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)$ is then a factorisation into irreducibles.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I am posting this under the [solution-verification] tag, and so I would like feedback or verification of a proposed solution.

Comment: Please include that as part of your post.  Specify if it is the entire solution or if there's a specific part that you're unsure of.

Comment: Alright, I have - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is excellent.

Just for thought, there are some other ways to show a general quadratic is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ when we don't need to also know the full factorization over $\mathbb{C}$.

- Since $x^2+1>0$ for every real $x$, it cannot have any real roots.
- More generally, we can complete the square: $3x^2 -18x + 32 = 3(x-3)^2 + 5 > 0$ for every $x$, so $3x^2-18x+32$ has no real roots.
- Check the discriminant $D=b^2-4ac$ in the quadratic formula: For $x^2+1$, $D=-4$. For $3x^2-18x+32$, $D=-60$. When the discriminant is negative, there are no real roots.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I probably won't use the discriminant though because we haven't explicitly mentioned or proved this result in class.

Comment: Though if you know the two complex roots of any quadratic are $\frac{b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$, it's pretty simple: $D>0$ means two distinct real roots, $D=0$ means one duplicate root, and $D<0$ means no real roots.